# how to know how weka give index to class

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to write a code in java by using weka library. my using dataset has two classes(True and False). my program generates a classifier by `buildClassifier()` method then classify test instances by `classifyInstance()` method. classifyInstance method returns index of the predicted class as a double.

My question is how do i know which class value takes which index number? For example, classifyInstance method returned 1 index for prediction. In here 1 index is class ture or class false?

Comment: Index of the class? What do you mean by this?

Comment: As i told, classifyInstance method returns index of the predicted class as a double. for example returning index is 1. Then is this class True or class False. How can i know that?

Comment: What does the docs say?

Comment: buildClassifier(): Generates a classifier. Must initialize all fields of the classifier that are not being set via options (ie. multiple calls of buildClassifier must always lead to the same result). Must not change the dataset in any way.
classifyInstance(): Classifies the given test instance. The instance has to belong to a dataset when it's being classified. Note that a classifier MUST implement either this or distributionForInstance().
Returns:
the predicted most likely class for the instance or Utils.missingValue() if no prediction is made